# When I calculate a large factorial, why do I get a negative number?

Tags: c++, signed, factorial

So, simple procedure, calculate a factorial number. Code is as follows.

```
int calcFactorial(int num)
{
    int total = 1;

    if (num == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    for (num; num > 0; num--)
    {
        total *= num;
    }

    return total;
}
```

Now, this works fine and dandy (There are certainly quicker and more elegant solutions, but this works for me) for most numbers. However when inputting larger numbers such as 250 it, to put it bluntly, craps out. Now, the first couple factorial "bits" for 250 are { 250, 62250, 15126750, 15438000, 3813186000 } for reference.

My code spits out { 250, 62250, 15126750, 15438000, **-481781296** } which is obviously off. My first suspicion was perhaps that I had breached the limit of a 32 bit integer, but given that 2^32 is 4294967296 I don't think so. The only thing I can think of is perhaps that it breaches a **signed** 32-bit limit, but shouldn't it be able to think about this sort of thing? If being signed is the problem I can solve this by making the integer unsigned but this would only be a temporary solution, as the next iteration yields 938043756000 which is far above the 4294967296 limit.

So, is my problem the signed limit? If so, what can I do to calculate large numbers (Though I've a "LargeInteger" class I made a while ago that may be suited!) without coming across this problem again?

Comment: To sum it up in one word: *Overflow*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

2^32 doesn't give you the limit for signed integers.

The signed integer limit is actually [2147483647](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/296az74e(VS.80).aspx) (if you're developing on Windows using the MS tools, other toolsuites/platforms would have their own limits that are probably similar).

You'll need a C++ large number library [like this one](http://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/).

Comment: For the curious, that number (2,147,483,647) is 2^31 - 1. The limit for unsigned integers is 2^32 - 1.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the other comments, I'd like to point out two serious bugs in your code.

- You have no guard against negative numbers.
- The factorial of zero is one, not zero.

Comment: I forgot about the fact that 0! = 1, but as said by Treb factorials are, by definition, non-negative numbers. But, one bug down!

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you hit the limit. An int in C++ is, by definition, signed. And, uh, no, C++ does not think, ever. If you tell it to do a thing, it will do it, even if it is obviously wrong.

Consider using a large number library. There are many of them around for C++.

Comment: LOL! 'C++ does not think, ever.' Great answer!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't specify signed or unsigned, the default is signed. You can modify this using a command line switch on your compiler.

Just remember, C (or C++) is a very low-level language and does precisely *what you tell it to do*. If you tell it to store this value in a signed int, that's what it will do. **You** as the programmer have to figure out when that's a problem. It's not the language's job.

Answer (score 1):

My Windows calculator (*Start-Run-Calc*) tells me that

```
hex (3813186000) =         E34899D0
hex (-481781296) = FFFFFFFFE34899D0
```

So yes, the cause is the signed limit. Since factorials can by definition only be positive, and can only be calculated for positive numbers, both the argument and the return value should be unsigned numbers anyway. (I know that everybody uses `int i = 0` in for loops, so do I. But that left aside, we should use always unsigned variables if the value can not be negative, it's good practice IMO).

The general problem with factorials is, that they can easily generate *very* large numbers. You could use a float, thus sacrificing precision but avoiding the integer overflow problem.

Oh wait, according to what I wrote above, you should make that an unsigned float ;-)

Answer (score -3):

If i remember well:

unsigned short int = max 65535

unsigned int = max 4294967295

unsigned long = max 4294967295

unsigned long long (Int64 )= max 18446744073709551615

#### Edited source:

[Int/Long Max values](http://home.att.net/%7Ejackklein/c/inttypes.html#int)

[Modern Compiler Variable](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables.html)

Comment: In most modern compilers, an int is the same as a long.

Comment: long long is a INT64 in MSDN documentation. My values are ok with modern compilers too. Have a nice day

Comment: Sorry this is plain wrong. Always refer to your compiler documentation for the CPU architecture you are working on. You don't even appear to be right for visual C++:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @Daok: Last time I checked (10 years ago) an 'int' was 32 bits. :)  Remember, the standard says sizeof(int) >= 2 and sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long), so in most 32-bit systems 'int' is 32-bit to match the native register size.

Comment: My C++ is old but I have edited to display the difference between Short int and int. Now confusion should be over.

Comment: You're not even reading your own references.
http://home.att.net/~jackklein/c/inttypes.html#int
Who is right? On any given compiler, one or the other could be right. On some compilers, both would be wrong. I know of one compiler for a 24 bit DSP where an int has 24 bits.